# Newton-Raphson method issue

Tags: newton-raphson

I have a quick question. I have a system of residuals in the form of

$$R_i= (\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j)-b_i$$

where $a_{ij}$ and $b_{i}$ are constants. I am trying to show that applying Newton-Raphson to this system of equations will converge to a solution in one iteration, independent of the initial guess. Does anyone have any ideas on demonstrating this?

Comment: The linear approximation to a linear function is the same function...

Comment: Right, I just have a hard time proving this mathematically with a system of equations.

Comment: Well, show the Jacobian of $f(x)=Ax-b$ is $A$, then check $A(x_0-A^{-1}(Ax_0-b))=b$. In the end this is exactly what I said, the linear approximation of $f(x)$ at any $x_0$ is just $f(x)$ itself. So because Newton's method sets the linear approximation equal to zero in each step, $f$ winds up equal to zero in the first step too.